# media queries internet explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, media-queries

i tried to use media queries in my sites. it works well in firefox and safari, but not for IE. does anyone know to make the media queries work well in IE(internet explorer 7 and 8).

here is the code : 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, media query is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 or older. You can use Javascript to hack around. See [these](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries)!
You can use `<!--[if lt IE <version>]>` for compatibility issues.

Answer (score 10):

Maybe this can also be useful:

To make  media queries work in IE8 or older, you can use [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond). 
Download the script file, copy it to your scripts folder (or wherever you like). Then put the line below into the head part of your html document (assuming you copied the file to the scripts folder).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/respond.js"></script>
```

And that's it. IE will start to support media queries.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this awesome script! Saved my life.